# IllegalAccessError when initializing Freemarker with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, freemarker

I'm trying to use Freemarker 2.3 with GAE 1.7.1 (I also make some tests with 1.8.1.1) but I have a very strange error occuring when Freemarker initializing:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class
   com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime can not access
   a member of class freemarker.log.Log4JLoggerFactory with modifiers ""
at freemarker.log.Logger.createFactory(Logger.java:335)
at freemarker.log.Logger.createFactory(Logger.java:304)
at freemarker.log.Logger.selectLoggerLibrary(Logger.java:163)
at freemarker.log.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:266)
at freemarker.template.utility.SecurityUtilities.<clinit>(SecurityUtilities.java:67)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.<clinit>(BeansWrapper.java:147)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper.<clinit>(ObjectWrapper.java:69)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at freemarker.core.Configurable.<init>(Configurable.java:139)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:142)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:127)
```

It happens when instantiating the Configuration object:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

I tried to change underlying logger with Logger.selectLoggerLibrary call but I have something similar...

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Can you specify exactly version of your Freemarker?
(sorry, I can't leave comments on questions)

Comment: Hello,
No problem! I'm using version 2.3.19 for GAE... Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you using GAE-compatible binary? [link!](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/FreeMarker-2-3-19-is-out-Please-read-security-notes-td4433766.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the freemarker-gae-2.3.19.jar file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting `LIBRARY_SLF4J` or `LIBRARY_COMMONS` with `Logger.selectLoggerLibrary`. Does the problem go away?

Update: I see why it does it for Log4J on GAE. Will be fixed in 2.3.20-gae.

Comment: Yes, adding the slf4j jar in classpath and using the LIBRARY_SLF4J fixed my problem! Thanks very much, Dániel!